# Tapping on tabbar in TabView while inside a NavigationView won't dismiss nested NavigationViews

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a very basic setup which involves `NavigationView`s inside a `TabView`. Within that `NavigationView`, users can go to other screens.

I would expect, like in other every app I have seen, is that when I tap on the current active tab, it jumps back to the initial `NavigationView`, dismissing all other `NavigationView`s active in that tab. However, when I press on the active tab, nothing happens.

Is there a property I must set to make this work?

Comment: Based on the information you provided, it would be hard for you to get a solution in the answers. Please follow the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and show us where the problem is, how you tried to solve it, include an example.

Comment: This kind of behavior is naturally happening for UIKit based application not SwiftUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe it not a standard SwiftUI behavior, and to make it worse you cannot detect the second tap on a TabBar icon. The only way I know is to use a custom TabBar setup, e.g. like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var currentTab = "Analytics"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView(selection: $currentTab) {
                VStack {
                    Text("Home Tab")
                }
                .tag("Home")
                
                VStack {
                    Text("Analytics Tab")
                }
                .tag("Analytics")
            }
            Divider()
            HStack {
                TabBarButton(imageName: "house.fill", label: "Home", current: $currentTab)
                TabBarButton(imageName: "chart.bar.fill", label: "Analytics", current: $currentTab)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TabBarButton: View {
    let imageName: String
    let label: String
    @Binding var current: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            if current == label {
                // reset your view
                print("reset")
            }
            current = label
        } label: {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: imageName)
                Text(label)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```